# Diversity gain in MIMO-OFDM system

Tags: ofdm, mimo

What is the diversity gain in $4\times2$ vs $2 \times 2$ MIMO system. Is it $10 \log \left( N_{t} - N_{r} \right)$?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's 0 dB!

You can derive that from the diversity order. Think about the criterion that maximizes that! What's the maximum of that criterion that a 2×2 and a 4×2 matrix could have?

Let's talk about the figures from the [Huawei Marketing Publication](https://www-file.huawei.com/-/media/corporate/pdf/mbb/2020/4x4-mimo.pdf?la=en) you cite (this is not a scientific paper, and the conflicts of interest are obvious). They cite these two Excel-generated figures:

---

### Fig. A: "CDF of Downlink Throughput in Drive Tests of China Telecom", P. 14

[image: CDF of Downlink Throughput in Drive Tests of China Telecom]

---

### Fig. B:  "Single Cell Coverage Test", P. 16

[image: Single Cell Coverage test drive]

## Work in Progress; gotta be somewhere.

---

Source for both is "China Telecom, 2017", which sadly isn't defined any further, so there's literally nothing that tells us what the measurement methodology here was. I'd say with this kind of undefinedness, the data presented isn't worth anything.

If we assume good intent (again, this is marketing material, so that actually requires some trust), we will allow ourselves to make qualitative observations from the graphs. I will not discuss the 7dB they claim they gain, as that does really not arise from these graphs, and there's no explaining done what that number actually means.  Discussing undefined gains makes no sense.

### Qualitative Observations based on the graphs.

Let's look at Fig. B first.

Comment: But this research from huawei shows significant gain. Can you have a quick look at Exhibit 8: CDF of Downlink Throughput in Drive Tests of China Telecom in this doc : https://www-file.huawei.com/-/media/corporate/pdf/mbb/2020/4x4-mimo.pdf?la=en

Comment: This is 26 pages of mostly marketing BS; could you tell me which page you're referring to?

Comment: On page 14, the 4×2 and 2×2 curves lie almost perfectly on each other, down to measurement accuracy, I'd argue.

Comment: See page 16 of 26 you can clearly see the gain of 4x2 vs 2x2.

Comment: On the same page it says "4x2 DL MIMO can provide 7 dB of link budget gain compared to 2x2 MIMO."

Comment: sorry, I meant the curves on page 14.